# html numeric input fileds

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post"> 
     <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>    
        <td>
          <form><input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score1" /></form> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <form><input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score2" /></form> 
        </td>     
      </tr>
   </table>
  <?php 
    global $score1;
    global $score2;
    echo "Score 1= " . $_POST['score1']. "    ";
    echo "Score 2= " . $_POST['score2']. "    ";
  ?> 
  <input type="submit"/> 
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

score1 gets displayed correctly, but score2 is always empty. I am running it inside wordpress template, could it cause this problem, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

because you are opening and closing the form before and after the all the text inputs.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post"> 
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>    
                <td><input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score1" />  
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score2" />    
            </td>     
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
            global $score1;
            global $score2;
            echo "Score 1= " . $_POST['score1']. "    ";
            echo "Score 2= " . $_POST['score2']. "    ";
        ?> 
        <input type="submit"/> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You cant create a form for each `<td>`
2. Also for easy dubugging, put your `PHP` code on the top then `html` files

Change below

```
<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>    
        <td><form> <input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score1" />  
        </form> 
        </td>
        <td><form> <input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score2" />    
        </form> 
        </td>     
      </tr>
   </table>
```

to

```
<?php 
    global $score1;
    global $score2;
    echo "Score 1= " . $_POST['score1']. "    ";
    echo "Score 2= " . $_POST['score2']. "    ";
  ?> 


        <form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post"> 
        <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>    
                <td><input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score1" /></td>
                <td><input type=number min="0" max="19" name="score2" /></td>     
              </tr>
           </table>

    <input type="submit"/> 
        </form>
```